# What makes the Forgotten Realms "forgotten"?

Tags: forgotten-realms, lore

If the Forgotten Realms are forgotten, who forgot them? Certainly not the inhabitants. Is there a lore explanation for why the Forgotten Realms are forgotten?

Comment: I used to know the answer to this question, but I no longer remember. ;-)

Comment: It sounds cool.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I wondered this before myself, I found that [Wikipedia had most of my answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgotten_Realms).

> The Forgotten Realms is a fantasy world setting, described as a world
>   of strange lands, dangerous creatures, and mighty deities, where magic
>   and supernatural phenomena are quite real. The premise is that, long
>   ago, the Earth and the world of the Forgotten Realms were more closely
>   connected. As time passed, the inhabitants of planet Earth have mostly
>   forgotten about the existence of that other world – hence the name
>   Forgotten Realms.

The AD&D 2nd edition *Player’s Guide to the Forgotten Realms Campaign* (TSR2142) explains on page 2 the name is based on its relation to our own world losing contact with and forgetting it:

> #### What are the Forgotten Realms?
>
> Some theorists explain dragons and other fantastic occurrences by postulating parallel worlds. In times past, they believe, travel between mundane worlds — like our own — and more exotic locales was easy and frequent. But we have lost contact, and lost the worlds themselves. Lost, or forgotten.
>
> Abeir-Toril, more commonly Toril, is an Earth-sized planet dominated by a continent in its northern hemisphere. Called Faerûn in the west, it is here that the Forgotten Realms lie. […]

Comment: Do you have a more direct source you can cite for that? Wikipedia is not a reliable source, and that statement in the Wikipedia article has no citation itself. Essentially, someone could've just completely made that up and could be completely wrong.

Comment: True, and I realized that too as I posted--I used to have a Forgotten Realms players handbook that said something of the sort, but that's just my word for it. Perhaps a better wiki link, with better sources, is Ed Greenwood's page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_Greenwood#cite_note-Dragon_#244-1

Comment: @TigerDM Are you thinking of the softcover with the whitish cover? I have that somewhere and can check.

Comment: I dug out my copy (ah, memories), and found the part to add to your answer. It's not quite as directly “it's called Forgotten because we (Earth humans) forgot it” as I remember either, but the implication is so tight that it overall conveys exactly that — hence us both remembering it saying so.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for proving that my mind isn't as old as my body ;)

Answer (score 47):

### Forgotten Realms was originally the place that Earth's fantasy legends came from.

From a profile on Ed Greenwood in *Dragon* magazine #244 (p. 112):

> The "Forgotten Realms" name originally came from the notion of a "multiverse" of parallel worlds.  Our Earth is one, the Realms another.  In Greenwood's original conception, Earth's fantastic legends derive from a fantasy world that we've now lost the way to—hence, the Forgotten Realms.  "Concerns over possible lawsuits (kids getting hurt while trying to 'find a gate') led TSR to de-emphasize this meaning," he says.

Answer (score 7):

Ed Greenwood explained the name "Forgotten Realms" on page 4 of *DM's Sourcebook of the Realms*, as included in the 1e *Forgotten Realms Campaign Set* (1987):

> ### Introductions
>
> **Ed Greenwood**
>
> Well met! Welcome to my world; the
> Forgotten Realms. A vast land, full of
> strange splendors—a living background
> for vivid adventure. Elminster took me
> there first.
>
> Welcome to *our* world. Now the Realms
> are yours, too; a world that has delighted
> me for almost twenty years in all its rich
> variety is presented herein—and in pages
> yet to come—for you to enjoy and set
> AD&D<sup>®</sup> game campaign play in. Only a
> small area of the Realms can be squeezed
> into these pages, so there's much to look
> forward to if you come along for the ride.
> It's been a long one for me thus far; the
> Realms began in 1968 as a setting for fantasy short stories, and later (1975) was
> developed and detailed, as the
> DUNGEONS & DRAGONS<sup>®</sup> system
> appeared. Regular play in the Realms
> began in 1978, and still continues; the
> present roster of regular players has
> remained intact since early 1980. As the
> ADVANCED DUNGEONS & DRAGONS<sup>®</sup>
> system has appeared, book by book, the
> Realms have been modified to conform
> with official rules, and these (with the
> unofficial additions published in
> DRAGON<sup>®</sup> magazine from issue #30
> onward, such as monsters, magical items,
> spells and nonplayer character classes)
> can be assumed to hold sway in the
> Realms now. I have always treated the
> Realms as a "real place" which I am viewing and reporting on rather than a deliberate creation, and I believe that has been
> the key to making it live.
>
> The "Forgotten Realms" derive their
> name from the fictitious fact upon
> which play in my campaign is based:
> that a multiverse exists, of countless
> parallel co-existing Prime Material
> Planes (including the world presented
> herein, our own modern "Earth," and
> any other fantasy settings a DM may
> wish to incorporate in play), all related
> to the Known Planes of Existence presented in the AD&D system. Travel
> betwixt these planes was once far more
> common than is the case now (when
> few know the means of reaching other
> worlds, or even believe in the existence
> of such fanciful places); hence, the
> Realms have been "forgotten" by beings
> of Earth. Our legends of dragons, vampires, and of other fearsome creatures
> and magic are due to this formerly
> widespread contact between the
> worlds; most have of course become
> confused and distorted with the passage of time and many retellings. That
> corner of the Realms presented herein
> is a strip of the heart of the western
> part of only one continent of Toril, that
> region known as Faerun (pronounced
> FAY-er-OON; the name meant "home" in
> a now-lost early human tongue). Much
> more awaits the traveler, to be revealed
> in later works.